# How to override parent style.css in woocommerce? Function.php file problem

Tags: php, css, wordpress

This is what bothers me.

This is my functions.php:

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'avada-stylesheet','avada- max-2c','avada-min-2c-max-3c','avada-min-3c-max-4c','avada-min-4c-max-5c','avada-min-5c-max-6c','avada-min-768-max-1024-p','avada-min-768-max-1024-l','avada-max-shbp-18','avada-max-shbp-32','avada-max-640','avada-min-768-max-1024-woo' ) );
}
endif;

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );    

if ( !function_exists( 'child_theme_configurator_css' ) ):
function child_theme_configurator_css() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_child', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent' ) );
    }
endif;

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_configurator_css', 20 );

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
```

An this is my style.css file in my child theme:

```
/*
Theme Name: Avada Child
Theme URI: http://avada.theme-fusion.com/
Template: Avada
Author: ThemeFusion
Author URI: http://themeforest.net/user/ThemeFusion
Description: The #1 selling theme of all time that allows you to build virtually any     design style.
Version: 5.7.2.1545428017
Updated: 2018-12-21 22:33:37

*/


.woocommerce-message {

padding-left: 18px;
background-color: #252a33;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128,1);
border-top-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128,1);
border-bottom-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
color: rgba(128,128,128,1);

}
```

My goal is to change background-color, but it doesn't work ... I used Child Theme Configurator plugin to make a child theme, and I think that plugin is responsible for that how function.php looks like...

Please help.

Paul

Comment: Are you able to make any other changes?

Comment: I guess not. I'm trying to do some changes in functions.php such as removing orderby-order-container but also nothing's happening... (remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );

Comment: Is your browser cache disabled?

Comment: no, it is not. I assume it shoud be, right?

Comment: ok, It is now disabled and cache is cleared, but still nothing happens...

Comment: Yes, it should be disabled. Does the stylesheet get loaded at all?

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm a beginner and actually don't know how to check if it's loading... Please have mercy for me.

Comment: I just discovered that this notification I am trying to change displays in different way when I am logged in as an administrator of my wordpress account... weird...

Comment: and it's only happens when admin is logged in. When I am logged in as ordinary user also the style override works fine... strange

Comment: That's quite strange.. this should mean that the stylesheet is getting loaded, but in case you need to know in the future, you can check that in your chrome developer tools. Just go to View > Developer > Developer Tools, and then select on Sources on top of the window that pops up.

Comment: Just to make sure, the issue seems to be resolved when logged out right?

Comment: Yes. All the customization I make in style.css works fine. Thank you for your help! I hope my case will spare some time few of you! Thank you Sheedo!

Comment: Sure, anytime :)